# No hibernate, sempre que eu alterar a configuração da Entity, eu tenho que dropar as tabela no banco de dados?

Tags: hibernate, tabela-banco-de-dados

Exemplo: eu tenho a classe Pessoa abaixo:

```
@Entity
public class Pessoa {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long idPessoa;
    private String nome;

    //getters e setters

}
```

O hibernate, por padrão, persiste no banco uma String como Varchar, e quero persistir no banco como text e altero para a seguinte configuração:

```
@Entity
public class Pessoa {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long idPessoa;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "text")
    private String nome;

    //getters e setters

}
```

Acrescentando a annotation "@Column(columnDefinition = "text")" no atributo String, e para isso persistir como text, estou dropando a tabela já criada no banco, e minha dúvida é a seguinte:

Teria uma forma de eu não precisar ficar dropando a tabela no banco de dados, visto que em um sistema mais complexo, isso pode me causar problemas de consistência?

Comment: Já trabalhei em um projeto que quando tinha essas mudanças a gente alterava na classe e dava um `alter` na coluna do banco. Não sei se é a melhor maneira, mas funcionava. Isso porque tinha vezes que o Hibernate não atualizava todas tabelas rodando com `update` ou deixava de criar alguma sequence.

Comment: @MaiconCarraro eu queria eliminar esse `alter` também, queria é ficar despreocupado com o banco, pra que eu entre o minimo possível no banco. Mesmo porque tem cliente que não gosta muito quando pedimos acesso ao banco

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12400825/jpa-data-too-long-for-column-does-not-change

Comment: entao @MaiconCarraro meu xml ta igual do tutorial la, e nada, ainda não modifica, to tendo que modificar pelo banco ainda

Comment: O tutorial ele só está simulando, `So in essence the create ( which first drops the table and then recreates) works correctly however the update does not if there is a modification in property metadata`. Na última resposta tem uma outra solução, mas não sei se funciona.

Comment: Esse tipo de alteração é sempre chato de gerenciar mesmo. Particularmente uso o [flywaydb](http://flywaydb.org/) para gerenciar toda DDL para mim, não uso JPA provider para isto, nele consigo gerenciar tudo, fazer *roolback* de alterações, etc.

Comment: @BrunoCésar como usa esse flywaydb?

Comment: @TiagoFerezin ele trabalha com conceito de migrates. Tu pode usar SQL puro ou java mesmo, descrevendo as migrates, para que seja feito o versionamento do schema da base. Veja na [documentação](http://flywaydb.org/documentation/) a ideia dele, os artigos e tal. Se realmente lhe atender, posso incluir um exemplo completo de uso dele.

Comment: @BrunoCésar pode colocar como resposta um exemplo, que se funcionar eu coloco como aceita, mas o que eu realmente queria, é algo no Hibernate mesmo. se possivel

Comment: O recurso do hibernate de criar ou alterar o banco conforme as anotações nas entidades só é adequado para usar em bases de produção se o sistema for mesmo muito simples e se a integridade dos dados nem for lá tão importante. A maioria dos sistemas não é assim. Provavelmente você terá que desenvolver ou escolher um processo e uma ferramenta à parte para fazer a migração do banco de dados em vez de contar com o Hibernate para isso.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correto, 
Pois quando você deixa que o hibernate gere as tabelas para você baseado em seus modelos, ele apenas cria coisas, e não deleta.

A não ser que você faça a seguinte configuração:

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop" />
```

- Porem ele vai deletar todo o banco e criar novamente cada vez que você iniciar seu servidor de aplicação.

A melhor forma é fazer este processo na mão mesmo, pois não é aconselhável em projetos rodando em produção deixar o hibernate fazer a manutenção em seu banco de dados.

O ideal é você uma estrutura em que ele verifique o que a de diferente no banco de dados e apenas mostre para você os scripts que você deve aplicar, como criação de tabelas e adição de campos. E o resto como alteração de nome de tabelas ou até exclusão de um campo ou tabela você faça o script na mão mesmo.